# Confusing box2d forces

Tags: physics, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

[image]

Hello Friends.
This is my demo game screen-shoot. Here i am using three buttons. Right-bottom button is used for jump and left-bottom buttons used for move left and right.

I have some questions
1) should i use linearImpuls for jump body??
2) For move right and left which types of force i applied???

PLease tell me i am confusing to use linearImpuls, applyforce and linearVelocity.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To jump you should use linear impulse upwards. To run you have a couple of options. You could apply a force which wil over time increase velocity. You would then need to limit the maximum velocity. This is done by applying damping. You also want the player to come to a complete stop when not pressing left or right. This is done by applying friction. Set friction and damping quite high to make the controls feel responsive.

You could also instead make a velocity check to see if you are moving to the right or left and apply an impulse if not. This will lead to a bit more jerky behaviour though (which might on the other hand be what you want)

Comment: Thanks mikael i am using linearImpuls fr jumping and force for movement left-right and for stoping friction used. But i have one problem in jumping when i press jump button once it jumps at that time i press jump button 2nd time it jump continuos but i don't want to do that. I want when player touch floor or wall or point that time jump will perform. How can i do this?? Sorry for poor english

Comment: I have another issue regarding your answer.How to limit the maximum velocity?? How can i use damping for limit jump??

Comment: Sorry but issue of jump is solved.But another issue is when player jump using impuls and movement is done using force so when player jump at simultaneously movement perform that time movement of player is gone high. what to do to resolve this speed??

Comment: please help me...

Comment: Your maximum velocity will be determined by the linear damping. Pretty much like if you are riding a bike, if you exert your maximum force you still won't go faster than a certain speed. I don't really understand you last question, could you clarify?

Comment: You could also just set the maximum speed yourself. That would make it look and move more like old school platformers.

Comment: Okay.My question is when i press jump button player jump perfectly but at jump player goes in air for some second at that time move buttons press so speed of player is increase suddenly and player looks like running on air

Comment: How to set maximum speed for player??

Comment: `if (moveRight.active==YES) 
    {   
            ballBody->SetActive(true);
        b2Vec2 locationworld=b2Vec2(10,0);
            //b2Vec2 force=b2Vec2(1.0,0);
        double mass=ballBody->GetMass();
   //       ballBody->SetLinearVelocity(locationworld);
       // ballBody->ApplyLinearImpulse(mass*locationworld, ballBody->GetWorldCenter());
        ballBody->ApplyForce(mass*locationworld, ballBody->GetWorldCenter());
  //      ballBody->SetLinearDamping(1.2f);
        
        NSLog(@"Speed Of Velocity Right: %f",ballBody->GetLinearVelocity().x);
    }`

Comment: Well, if you don't want the player to be able to change direction in the air make sure that the feet are touching the ground before applying force :) Actually this is probably best done using a sensor around the feet rather than check for feet collision with ground as the feet may not actually exactly touch the ground every frame.

Answer (score 0):

How can i set maximum speed?? Because i am set one force when i press move button

```
if (moveRight.active==YES) 
    {   
            ballBody->SetActive(true);
        b2Vec2 locationworld=b2Vec2(10,0);
            //b2Vec2 force=b2Vec2(1.0,0);
        double mass=ballBody->GetMass();

        ballBody->ApplyForce(mass*locationworld, ballBody->GetWorldCenter());
  //      ballBody->SetLinearDamping(1.2f);

        NSLog(@"Speed Of Velocity Right: %f",ballBody->GetLinearVelocity().x);
    }
```

This condition is in update method. So where i set maximum speed??

Comment: This should maybe either be a part of your question (using edit) or another question altogether. Anyway, I haven't used cocos2D but you should be able to check the length of the linear velocity vector and if it is faster (longer) than max speed then set the vector to have length of maxspeed. Or, if it is only x-speed you wish to limit then set it to maxspeed instead.

Comment: But sir how can i set maxspeed??

Comment: Try: if (ballBody.Velocity.X > MAX_SPEED ) ballBody.Velocity.X = MAX_SPEED; if (ballBody.Velocity.X < -MAX_SPEED ) ballBody.Velocity.X = -MAX_SPEED;